# Is there a way to use a function parameter as another parameter of the same function?

Tags: python, string, search, substring

I'm new to Python and stackoverflow and I'm defining a Python function similar to the inbuilt `find()` that takes a string and a substring as an argument and two optional arguments specifying the starting and the ending index.
I want to keep the latter two arguments optional by specifying default parameters. But I want the ending index to be the length of the first argument by default:

```py
    def search(string, substr, start = 0, end = len(string)):
        lenss = len(substr)
        while start < end:
            if string[start : lenss] == substr:
                return start
            start += 1
            lenss += 1
        return False
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    def search(string, substr, start = 0, end = len(string)):
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
```

What I have tried is setting the last parameter to `None` and adding a guardian:

```py
def search(string, substr, start = 0, end = None):
    if end is None:
           end  = len(string)
    lenss = len(substr)
    while start < end:
        if string[start : lenss] == substr:
            return start
        start += 1
        lenss += 1
    return False
```

This gets the job done but I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do this and is there a way to assign one parameter to an another one of the same function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're doing is fine... except you should really use `if end is None` instead of `==`...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for letting me know that. I'll edit the post

Comment: Default parameter values in Python are evaluated *once*, when the function was originally defined.  It's therefore impossible for them to refer to other parameters that won't even exist until the function is actually called.

Comment: Thank you! @jasonharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it here is a good and correct way to do it:
(cleaned up spacing a bit to be more conventional)

```
def search(string, substr, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(string)
```

An other way it's commonly done is:

```
def search(string, substr, start=0, end=None):
    end = len(string) if end is None else end
```

Unfortunately there's really no other good way; a function parameter cannot refer to another parameter, since the default parameter values are evaluated only when the function is defined. When evaluting them on the definition it's not possible to evaluate `end=len(string)`, since it cannot be know what `string` is when it's passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!